# Two Blocks for sort filter Views — Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view in Drupal 7 with results including a field of date and another with price, I need to sort the results by means of these two fields when I click on the appropriate link (not button or dropbox radio), but the trick is I need add the different **sort filter** into two separate blocks, because each block will have a different per user context.

Besides the filters should be links. Any idea how to work this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have different displays for all order variations and then use appropriate one depending on parameter passed with link. Of course, you can't just use block view, but create your custom block which will embed correct view depending on that parameter.

Other way would be altering view query. In you module add hook function for altering view and inside you should detect your view, check for parameter and alter order value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two block displays for the same view, each of them sorting the results with a different criteria. Once both blocks are created, enable them in the same theme region and establish the URLs in which each module should be displayed. This configuration can be set using the block configuration form.